# How to read data from firebase node created using push

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I managed to create A database in firebase and I inserted some data. Each row has a unique key, but I am unable to retrieve the data. I am using android studio.

[image: My firebase stucture]

This is the way I am retrieving username and user_id on listView but I got nothing :

```
  ......     

       String url = "https://myydatabase_url.com/users.json";
       StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,      new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Users.this);
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, Chat.class));
        }
    });
}

public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                // add key on array list
                al.add(key);
            }
   .....
```